# Streamlines for steady flow problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, kinematics

I need to calculate the streamlines for the steady flow given by the velocity field
$$\mathbf{u}=(u,v,w) = \left( 0,\frac{y}{y^2 +z^2} , \frac{z}{y^2 +z^2}\right)$$

Now I've been able to notice that $\dfrac{ \partial y}{ \partial z} = \dfrac{y}{z}$ therefore $y = ze^{c}$ but I'm not sure how I should continue. I've tried to solve $\dfrac{ \partial y}{ \partial s} = \dfrac{y}{y^2+z^2}$ but I get a $y^{z^2}$ term in my answer which makes me doubt whether I'm doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to draw out the velocity field, you would see that it is going outward. In fact if you were really astute, you would notice that your velocity has the same form as the electric field from a wire. This should help you visualize the field.

Because of the symmetry, it makes sense to work in cylindrical coordinates. The position along the axis will be given by $x$, and $r$ and $\phi$ correspond to $y$ and $z$. Then by your formula $y=ze^c$, or in other words $y=kz$ with $k$ independent of time, we know that $\phi$ is constant.

So all that remains is to find the time dependence of $r$. We know $\dot{r}=1/r$, so integrating we get $r(t)^2 - r(t_0)^2 = 2(t-t_0)$, so that $r(t) = \sqrt{2(t-t_0) + r(t_0)^2}$.

If you want the solution in the original coordinates, you just have to do a coordinate transformation.